# Possible to change these lengthy codes to a recursion function?

Tags: python, recursion, docx, python-docx, nested-table

I am trying to get data from tables (which includes nested tables as well) in a .docx document. However my current code which looks like:

```
def pctnt():
    tables = doc.tables
    for table in tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    print(paragraph.text)
                for table in cell.tables:
                    for row in table.rows:
                        for cell in row.cells:
                            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                                print(paragraph.text)
                            for table in cell.tables:
                                for row in table.rows:
                                    for cell in row.cells:
                                        for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                                            print(paragraph.text)
```

It works OK for my current .docx as I know how many nested tables there would be.

However, this is not going to be the case when I have other documents coming in, therefore I need a way to retrieve the data from nested tables no matter how many are there in the document.

> NEW QUESTION based on the solution given by @Boendal

Is it possible for me to print the data into a list so i can print a beautified table using pandas or search for a specific table cell?

Comment: To me it doesn't look like your current code requires you to know the number of tables, so it should work with any number of tables. But perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Something like `def iterate(thing): try: for item in thing: iterate(item); except TypeError: print(item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the description you gave and your code fragment this should work:

```
def print_paragraphs(doc):
    for table in doc.tables:
        for row in table.row:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    print(paragraph.text)
                print_paragraphs(cell)

print_paragraphs(doc)
```

Comment: NICE!! THIS WORKS PERFECTLY! I hopee.... tested and i think this will do. Thanks @Boendal You solved it like within seconds whereas i was searching high and low for a solution.